# How to give a unique style to a fee on WooCommerce

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, fee

I created a custom fee on Woocommerce based on a user plan. I did something like this on my `functions.php`:

```php
function my_discount_based_on_user_membership( $cart ) {
    $discount = 10;
    $cart->add_fee( "My Discount", -$discount );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'my_discount_based_on_user_membership', 20, 1 );
```

Let's say that this fee has the value of -$10. I want that -$10 have another color, like red for example. Is there a way of set a CSS class for a custom fee in Woocommerce? How can I target this element?

Since I could have another discounts later, target the element position using JS or CSS probably is not a good idea. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give a unique style to a fee in WooCommerce

Use CSS

```css
.fee bdi {
    color: red;
}
```

---

OR

You could overwrite the [cart/cart-totals.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/b19500728b4b292562afb65eb3a0c0f50d5859de/templates/cart/cart-totals.php) template file

- This template can be overridden copying it to `yourtheme/woocommerce/cart/cart-totals.php.`

Replace (line 61 @version 2.3.6)

```php
<td data-title="<?php echo esc_attr( $fee->name ); ?>"><?php wc_cart_totals_fee_html( $fee ); ?></td>
```

With

```php
<td style="color:red;" data-title="<?php echo esc_attr( $fee->name ); ?>"><?php wc_cart_totals_fee_html( $fee ); ?></td>
```

AND

the [checkout/review-order.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/b19500728b4b292562afb65eb3a0c0f50d5859de/templates/checkout/review-order.php) file

- This template can be overridden by copying it to `yourtheme/woocommerce/checkout/review-order.php.`

Replace (line 80 @version 5.2.0)

```php
<td><?php wc_cart_totals_fee_html( $fee ); ?></td>
```

With

```php
<td style="color:red;"><?php wc_cart_totals_fee_html( $fee ); ?></td>
```

*Note:* instead of using inline CSS,
when overwriting the template files. You can also add a custom class instead `<td class="my-class"...`